# How to wait for loading images in canvas

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, canvas, selenium-webdriver

My test needs to interact with the image loaded in canvas.

But I have no idea how to implement the wait of loading the image. 
If I expect only canvas tests are beginning to interact with it, while the image is still loaded.

I have to use driver.sleep(), but this is a bad and unreliable solution.
There are a part of page code with canvas:

```
<canvas class='ol-unselectable' width='816' height='400' style='width: 100%; height: 100%;'></canvas>
```

Also, the application is written in Angular.

The Network tab in the developer console in the browser shows that at the time of loading images is Img request.

I think, it is possible to write some code to check the load the image into canvas in the browser and use it via js executor.

But I have  not idea how do it. Help me please.

UPD. I try build custom waiting condition:

```
exports.isAllImageLoad = function isAllImageLoad(driver) {
    return new Condition('image loading', function(driver) {
        return driver.executeScript(
            'var img = new Image();' +
            'img.onload = function() { return true; };' +
            'img.onload()'
        ).then(function(result) {
            console.log('image loading: ' + result);
            return result;
        });
    });
};
```

and use it with:

```
return driver.wait(isAllImageLoad(driver), waitTimeOut);
```

But console show  me thah result of `img.onload()` is `null`.

UPD.i try use this code:

```
exports.isAllImageLoad = function isAllImageLoad(driver) {
    return new Condition('image loading', function(driver) {
        return driver.executeScript(
            'var image = new Image();' +
            'function mainLoop(){' +
                'if(image.complete){' +
                    'return true;' +
                '}else{' +
                    'return false;' +
                '}' +
            '}' +
            'mainLoop();'
        ).then(function(result) {
            console.log('image loading: ' + result);
            return result;
        });
    });
};
```

But the same returns `null`.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. All solutions propose to use the image url, but the fact is that the images load is different, depending on the previous actions of the user.

Comment: I try build custom waiting condition:
`exports.isAllImageLoad = function isAllImageLoad(driver) {
 return new Condition('image loading', function(driver) {
  return driver.executeScript(
   'var img = new Image();' +
   'img.onload = function() { return true; };' +
   'img.onload()'
  ).then(function(result) {
   console.log('image loading: ' + result);
   return result;
  });
 });
};`
and use it with:
`return driver.wait(isAllImageLoad(driver), waitTimeOut);`
But console show  me thah result is `null`.

Answer (score 1):

The is an alternative approch to waiting for the onload.

When the DOM has done all it can with the image and it has loaded, or the image has failed to load it sets the semaphore `image.complete` to true.

You can use that semaphore to determine whether or not it is safe to render the image.

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = "imageURI";
function mainLoop(){
     if(image.complete){
          ctx.drawImage(image,0,0,100,100);
     }else{
          ctx.fillRect(0,0,100,100); // image placeholder
     }
     requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
mainLoop();
```

This allows you to continue rendering while images are loading.

Though you can not tell directly if the image has loaded or there is an error.

An alternative is to attach your own semaphore.

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = "imageURI";
image.onload =  function(){this.ready=true}
```

And use the ready semaphore to indicate that the image is ready to render.

Comment: i try use your code like this:
`exports.isAllImageLoad = function isAllImageLoad(driver) {
 return new Condition('image loading', function(driver) {
  return driver.executeScript(
   'var image = new Image();' +
   'function mainLoop(){' +
    'if(image.complete){' +
     'return true;' +
    '}else{' +
     'return false;' +
    '}' +
   '}' +
   'mainLoop();'
  ).then(function(result) {
   console.log('image loading: ' + result);
   return result;
  });
 });
};`
But the same returns `null`.

Comment: Or you can use naturalWidth which must be set when the image has loaded (0 width images won't load)

Comment: @Valentina that will not work. You just create an image. Images need a src as URL or DataURL and even the checking for complete is a polling method, the odds of the function returning true one the first call in the same execution context is very low.

Answer (score 0):

You can place all your code inside the `image` [onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) event that you wanna process after the image has been successfully loaded.

**DEMO**
*(drawing an image on canvas after its been loaded successfully)*

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
ctx.font="50px Arial";
ctx.fillText('Loading...', 300, 200);
var image = new Image();
image.src = 'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/e9/dc/10/e9dc10141d0b4e5c9e360cc5669e65ed.jpg';
image.onload = function() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 816, 480)
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
}
```

```css
#canvas {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" class="ol-unselectable" width="816" height="400" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></canvas>
```

Comment: I use UI tests, I cant put my code into onload event, I need just wait until image has been loaded

Comment: @Valentina you can use diffrent  [CustomEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent) handler. that will fire on every successful load of an image